# How to turn off .BAK file creation in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I updated to Visual Studio 2017, and now my project directories are being cluttered with .bak files corresponding to files I modify. For example, if I edit a file named LintLicker.cs, the next day when I load my project, I'll notice LintLicker.cs.bak.

I can't find an option setting that controls whether or where .bak files get created. How can I stop this clutter--preferably by changing the location where backup files get created, but if necessary just preventing VS from creating them?

Comment: Are you using add-ins like DevExpress by chance?

Comment: This is no feature of Visual Studio itself. I've never seen this behaviour. Turning off extensions may help you find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks, guys! It turns out you were right. VS truly was not the program creating these files. I hope SO deletes my question, since it isn't relevant and the answer won't help others.

Answer (score 2):

This clutter was not caused by Visual Studio. I discovered the culprit was another program on my system.

Answer (score 2):

```
FileName.txt
FileName.txt.bak
```

For me, the `.bak` file was getting generated by Notepad++.

It seems that in Notepad++ version 8.3, the default setting is to create this backup file.  (I'm not sure what other versions have this as the default.)

To turn it off, use the menu bar:

1. `Settings->Preferences`
2. `Backup`
3. `Backup on save`
4. [set to] `None`

[image: Notepad++ Menu Bar]

[image: Notepad++ Backup on save]

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to uncheck the checkbox in VS 2017:

```
Extras->Options->Environment->AutoRecover
```

Comment: For me, it's Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Autorecover (I have no Extras option).